# How to get previous/next index of clicked button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I want to know that next button of the button I clicked and then compare that is it clicked or not. If I clicked button of index `a[5]` then I have to compare that `a[4]` and `a[6]` is clicked or not . If either of button is selected previously then only I can select `a[5]`. Thanks in Advance

```
private void GetControls()
{
    count++;
    for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
            btn.ID = i + "." + j;
            btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
            // btn.Click += btn_Click;
            flag = true;
            btn.CommandName = i + "-" + j;

            if (count==1)
            {
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);                   
            }
        }
    }   
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    count++;

    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string ID = (sender as Button).ID;
    string text = (sender as Button).Text;


    Label1.Text = " Congrates! Your meeting time has been sheduled between" + ID;
}
```

Comment: This is webforms code, not MVC

Comment: why dont you save the button number in a variable in session and check there?

Comment: ya i did that but i dont know how to check ...for that also i have to check its previous/next button id is present or not  in the list  ..that code i want how to get previous/next index  ...here is code             //List<string> createdControls = Session["Controls"] != null ? Session["Controls"] as List<string> : new List<string>();
                        //if (!createdControls.Contains(btn.ID)) createdControls.Add(btn.ID);
      //Session["Controls"] = createdControls;